# Allowing the user to record after the <Dial> verb times out

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

If someone calls our Twilio number, I want it to dial our office phone number, and if no one answers, I want the caller to be able to leave a message.  I've tried the following Twiml, and although the second sound bite plays, it does not record a message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play>http://domain.tld/file.wav</Play>
    <Dial timeout="10">+15555555555</Dial>
    <Play>http://domain.tld/pleaseleaveamessage.wav</Play>
    <Record action="/voicemail/" maxLength="30" />
</Response>
```

I've also tried passing an action to the  verb, and then trying the recording the in the action handler, but that also does not work.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here.

So, I actually took a copy of the above and tried it with my own account/numbers/URLs, and everything seemed fine. I would suggest you use your [call logs](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/calls) to look into it. If you open up one of your test calls, have a look at the Twilio Request Inspector, this should allow you to see what is going on, or if you are getting any errors.

As I say, it should work fine, and I had the same thing working here.

You may want to contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) on help@twilio.com.

Good luck!